# HTML CD-ROM database doesn't work in Windows 10

Tags: .net, vbscript, frames, cd-rom, macromedia

I have a rare CD-ROM database of a biography from the early 1900s. It is HTML and web-based. It installs as 2 separate CDs (which are stored as .ISO files) onto the hard drive.

I can then launch the search page with the icon that is created on the desktop, but when I try to do a search, nothing happens. No popup blockers are in effect that I am aware of, just nothing at all happens. However, this CD database worked fine previously.

The only weird things are that even when it did work, it only worked on Internet Explorer (possibly version 8?) and for whatever reason would not work on Chrome or Firefox. I am guessing the issue may have been introduced after I upgraded to Windows 10 last year.

[image: The Complete Edgar Cayce Readings Version 2.0, Home Page, in Google Chrome]

**Fig 1. This is what the CD-Rom's web interface start/home page looks like in Chrome**

---

[image: The Complete Edgar Cayce Readings Version 2.0, Simple Search Page, in Google Chrome]

**Fig 2. Simple Search page (after clicking "Word Search" in left menu), Chrome**

---

### My setup

```
OPERATING SYSTEM:
- Microsoft Windows: 10.0.14393 64-bit

BROWSERS:
- Google Chrome: 60.0.3112.66 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)
- Firefox: 54.0.1 (32-bit)
- Microsoft Edge: 40.15063.0.0
- Internet Explorer: 11.483.15063.0
- Chrome Canary: 61.0.3158.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)
- Torch Browser: 55.0.0.12195
- Comodo IceDragon: 52.0.0.4 (32-bit)
```

### What I have tried

The first thing I did was try other browsers, all to no avail. The first time an error appears is when the "Search" button in top menu is clicked. The second error appears if "Word Search" in the left menu is pressed, a term is chosen to search for, and then the "Search" button pressed on the resulting "Simple Search" page. However, I inspected the developer console and got a slightly different message for each:

### Chrome

*Search-Top*

> leftmenuframe.htm:19
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: MM_goToURL is not defined
>
> at HTMLImageElement.onclick (file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Edgar%20Cayce%20Readings/leftmenuframe.htm:19:323)

*Search-Left*

> simplesearchform.html:28
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: set_cookie is not defined
>
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick (file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Edgar%20Cayce%20Readings/simplesearchform.html:28:94)

### Firefox

*Search-Top*

> ReferenceError: MM_goToURL is not defined
>
> file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Edgar%20Cayce%20Readings/leftmenuframe.htm
>
> Line 1

*Search-Left*

> ReferenceError: set_cookie is not defined
>
> file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Edgar%20Cayce%20Readings/simplesearchform.html
>
> Line 1

#### Edge:

*Search-Top*

> Current window: /C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Edgar%20Cayce%20Readings/default.htm
>
> Current window: /C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Edgar%20Cayce%20Readings/default.htm
>
> SCRIPT5009: 'MM_goToURL' is undefined
>
> leftmenuframe.htm (19,101)

*Search-Left*

> SCRIPT5009: 'set_cookie' is undefined
>
> simplesearchform.html (28,55)

### Internet Explorer

I got a message about allowing ActiveX. Even after I OK'd that, these errors popped up in the console:

*Search-Top*

> DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
>
> default.htm
>
> HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
>
> default.htm
>
> HTML1524: Invalid HTML5 DOCTYPE. Consider using the interoperable form "".
>
> default.htm (1,1)
>
> Current window: /C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Edgar%20Cayce%20Readings/default.htm
>
> SCRIPT5009: 'MM_goToURL' is undefined
>
> leftmenuframe.htm (19,101)

*Search-Left*

### Canary

*Search-Top*

> leftmenuframe.htm:19
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: MM_goToURL is not defined
>
> at HTMLImageElement.onclick (file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Edgar%20Cayce%20Readings/leftmenuframe.htm:19:323)

*Search-Left*

> simplesearchform.html:28
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: set_cookie is not defined
>
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick (file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Edgar%20Cayce%20Readings/simplesearchform.html:28:94)

### Torch

*Search-Top*

> leftmenuframe.htm:19
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: MM_goToURL is not defined
>
> at HTMLImageElement.onclick (file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Edgar%20Cayce%20Readings/leftmenuframe.htm:19:323)

*Search-Left*

> VM39 simplesearchform.html:28
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: set_cookie is not defined
>
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick (file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Edgar%20Cayce%20Readings/simplesearchform.html:28:94)

### IceDragon

*Search-Top*

> ReferenceError: MM_goToURL is not defined[Learn More]  leftmenuframe.htm:1:1

*Search-Left*

> The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it.  search_options.htm
>
> The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it. cookiesManager.htm
>
> ReferenceError: set_cookie is not defined[Learn More]  simplesearchform.html:1:1
>
> A form was submitted in the windows-1252 encoding which cannot encode all Unicode characters, so user input may get corrupted. To avoid this problem, the page should be changed so that the form is submitted in the UTF-8 encoding either by changing the encoding of the page itself to UTF-8 or by specifying accept-charset=utf-8 on the form element.  simplesearchform.html
>
> The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it.  cookiesManager.htm

### My questions

1. What is the root issue? How can I get my installed CD-Rom web application to work again?
2. Can this be fixed by updating Windows, drivers, or other software?
3. If this can't be fixed by software installs or updates, is there a simple way to hack (rename file types, replace deprecated functions, etc.) it so it will work with modern operating systems and browsers?

### Update

By request I am adding the source code of the files as they read in Notepad++. The programming and functional parts appear to be in **Visual Basic**. I don't know much about VB at all, but it seems a lot of the characters are garbage, and possibly obfuscated. If there is some way to view the characters as "not garbage", please let me know!

#### simplesearch.html

```html
<HTML><HEAD>
  <title>Edgar Cayce Readings SimpleSearch</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<body bgcolor="#FEE7F5" background="images/leftmaingraygradient.jpg">
<OBJECT id=CookieScript type=text/x-scriptlet height=0 width=0 
data=cookiesManager.htm VIEWASTEXT>
 </OBJECT>
  <script LANGUAGE="VBScript.Encode">#@~^shAAAA==@#@&P~,P,PP,@!eRO@#@&@#@&,P~~,PP,oE mYbGUPk+D{^WGVb+c#@#@&P,P~~,PP~~,P~P,~EOR O OO O RO ORO ORR OO RO OO RRO O ORORR ORO RO O@#@&,PP~~,P~P,~,P~,PEP?Y,CV^POtPdnmDm4~\mDkm8s+kPDW~x;s^Pn61nwD@#@&~,PP~~,P~P,~,P~,B,0WMPD4+,?nlMm4)^V@#@&~P,PP,~~P,P,P~P~v ORO RO ORR OORR ORO R OR O OO O RO ORO ORR OO RO @#@&,~~P,P,P~P~~,P~P9Gm!:nUDRbsscZGW0r?^MkaYRU+D/WK3r+n+z~r26m^YhtDmdnJBP|@#@&P~~,P~P,~P,P~~,PP~~,P~P,~,P~,P,PP,P,~P,P~P,P~~,PP,~P,PP,~~P,P,P~\8H!Vs?D.k o@#@&,PP~~,P~P,~,P~,P9Wm!:UYcbsVcZGG0k+U^DbwYcjnY;WK3r+FnHPE2X^V!NnEBP{@#@&,P~P,~,P~,P,PP,P,~P,P~P,P~~,PP,~P,PP,~~P,P,P~P~~,P~P,~P,P~~,\4H;^VjYMr o@#@&P,PP,P,~P,P~P,P~[KmEsnxDRb^s ZKW0kn?^.bwORUnY;WGVb+|nz,Jj+m.1tEBP|@#@&,P,~P,P~P,P~~,PP,~P,PP,~~P,P,P~P~~,P~P,~P,P~~,PP~~,P~P,~,P~,\(1E^VUODbxL@#@&P~~,PP,~P,PP,~~P9W1Eh+UOcbsVc/WK3rnUmDr2DRj+D/KWVb+n+X,JUnlMm4b^VES,{@#@&~P,PP,~~P,P,P~P~~,P~P,~P,P~~,PP~~,P~P,~,P~,P,PP,P,~P,P~P,P~~,PP,jkswVjnlMm4RO6Ojl.m4)V^R#C^E+@#@&,P~P,~,P~,P,PP,P,~P,P~P,P~~,PP,~P,PP,~~P,P,P~P~~,P~P,~P,P~~,PP~~@#@&~P,~,P~,P,PP,P,~NKm;:xO mVVc/WK3kj^DbwDRj+O/KWVkF+HPEK8{w.GXkhkDzr~m@#@&iddidi7did7\(1;s^?YMrxT@#@&i7[W1Es+UY C^V ZKG3b+j^MkwO U+OZKG0knn+HPJh |2DK6r:bYzEBP{@#@&diddi77didi\81;s^?ODbUo@#@&779Wm;hxORms^R/KW0k+UmMrwDRj+DZGG0k+nnX,Jn2m2DK6b:rYzEBPm@#@&7did77idd7774HE^sUY.bxT@#@&,P,~P,P~P,P~~,PPERO OO RRO O ORORR ORO RO ORR OORR ORO R OR O OO O @#@&,P~P,P~~,PP,~P,PB,jnY,l^V~Y4n,W2YbGxmV~-mDkC8^+d@#@&~,P~,P,PP,P,~P,PvO ORR OO RO OO RRO O ORORR ORO RO ORR OORR ORO R O@#@&P,PP,P,~P,P~P,P~[KmEsnxDRl^s ZKW0kn?^.bwORUnY;WGVb+|nz,JPWar1JS,{@#@&didi7did7\(1;s^?YMrxT@#@&i77didid7d77@#@&7P,~P9W^;s+xO mVsR;GK3r?1DkaYcj+DZGW0knFXPrHEs4+MESP|@#@&d7d77id7\(HE^VjOMkxL@#@&d7di7id7@#@&,PP,P,~P,P~P,P~~9Wm!h+ YRzssR;WK3r+j^Mk2Ycj+DZGG0k+FnHPEbTnr~~|@#@&PP,P,~P,P~P,P~~,PP,~P,PP,~~P,P,P~P~~,P~P,~P,P~~,PP~~,P~P,~,P~,P,\4gE^s?DDrxT@#@&~,PP,~P,PP,~~P,P9W^Ehn Y b^sR;WGVb+?^.bwORUnDZGK3b+|X,EbT+/lDJS~|@#@&,~P,PP,~~P,P,P~P~~,P~P,~P,P~~,PP~~,P~P,~,P~,P,PP,P,~P,P~P,P~~,PP781!VVUO.k o@#@&~P~~,P~P,~P,P~~,NW^;s+UYc)^V ;WK3k?1.kaY ?Y/GK3kF+HPJGG^KHwJSPm@#@&P~P,~P,P~~,PP~~,P~P,~,P~,P,PP,P,~P,P~P,P~~,PP,~P,PP,~~P,P,P~P~~,\81!sVUY.r o@#@&~,P~P,~,P~,P,PP,NK^Es+UYcbsscZWKVk?mMr2Yc?Y/WGVb+F+H~J"+d;^Y?nOr~~{@#@&,P~,P,PP,P,~P,P~P,P~~,PP,~P,PP,~~P,P,P~P~~,P~P,~P,P~~,PP~~,P~P,~8!T@#@&,PP,P,~P,P~P,P~~9Wm!h+ YRzssR;WK3r+j^Mk2Ycj+DZGG0k+FnHPE?ar~~|@#@&PP,P,~P,P~P,P~~,PP,~P,PP,~~P,P,P~P~~,P~P,~P,P~~,PP~~,P~P,~,P~,P,\4gE^s?DDrxT@#@&~,PP,~P,PP,~~P,P9W^Ehn Y b^sR;WGVb+?^.bwORUnDZGK3b+|X,E?KDOAHJS~|@#@&,~P,PP,~~P,P,P~P~~,P~P,~P,P~~,PP~~,P~P,~,P~,P,PP,P,~P,P~P,P~~,PP781!VVUO.k o@#@&~P~~,P~P,~P,P~~,NW^;s+UYc)^V ;WK3k?1.kaY ?Y/GK3kF+HPJInCDr~,{@#@&~~,P~P,~P,P~~,PP~~,P~P,~,P~,P,PP,P,~P,P~P,P~~,PP,~P,PP,~~P,P,P~P-8gEsVUODbxL@#@&PP~~,P~P,~,P~,P,NW1EsnxDRCV^R/GK3kjmMkwD j+DZKWVknFX~Jg;:(+.EBP{@#@&id7di7id-(1!VVUYMrxT@#@&@#@&d7[KmEsnxDRl^s ZKW0kn?^.bwORUnY;WGVb+|nz,J/lDnTW.HJBP{@#@&i7did7diJ)JdJ@#@&~P,PP,~~P,P,P~P~v ORO RO ORR OORR ORO R OR O OO O RO ORO ORR OO RO @#@&,~~P,P,P~P~~,P~PE~0M+d4,/+C.1t~Dd!VOkPkYlMYk~W P2lT+~q@#@&P,~P,PP,~~P,P,P~BRR ORO RO ORR OORR ORO R OR O OO O RO ORO ORR OO R@#@&PP,~~P,P,P~P~~,P[W1;:xO zVV /KWVkj1DraYc?+DZKG3b+F+HPEKmo+|Ul7J~,m@#@&,P,P~P~~,P~P,~P,P~~,PP~~,P~P,~,P~,P,PP,P,~P,P~P,P~~,PP,~P,PP,~~P74gEsVjOMkUo@#@&P,P~~,PP~~,P~P,~EOR O OO O RO ORO ORR OO RO OO RRO O ORORR ORO RO O@#@&,PP~~,P~P,~,P~,PEPk NaP8Pr/,Y4n,V+6O:mkx,W.ls+@#@&~P~~,P~P,~P,P~~,BORR ORO R OR O OO O RO ORO ORR OO RO OO RRO O OROR@#@&P~P,~P,P~~,PP~~,hrx9GSRKmDxYc0MC:/cF*RsG1lYbGxctDW~',Jk+CD^4ctO:r@#@&,P~~,PP~3 N~s!U1YrKx,PP@#@&,~P,P~P,@#@&~,PP,vP,P0!U^YbW Pd+Om1WG3bn{xOnM`#~~,P~P,@#@&P~,P,PP@#@&,~P,P~B,P~~b0PUr:aV+UnCD1tcYaYjnmD^tzsVc\Cs!+@!@*jb:2Vjl.1tcY6D?CD1tP+sw -mVE~Y4+x@#@&7BidUkhwsnU+CD14RD6OjlD^4:+hwc-mV;'Uk:aVj+mD^tcYaOU+lM^tzVVc-CV!+@#@&7B7@#@&dvd,~+^/n@#@&dB77k+O{1GK3r`*@#@&iBi~P,+UN,kW7@#@&dE7P,PPEnUN,k6d~P~~,P~P@#@&P,P~~EPP~n N~0!U1YrKx@#@&@#@&P,~P,P~PwEU^DkW ~D/+DmWDm:`b@#@&~,P~P,~P,P~~,P@#@&~,P~P,~,P~,P,P@#@&P,~P,P~P,P~~,PP,vO OO RRO O ORORR ORO RO ORR OORR ORO R OR O OO O R@#@&P~P,P~~,PP,~P,PPE~rx9+XP+Prd,Y4+,.kTtOhxEW.m:nP6.m:n@#@&,PP,P,~P,P~P,P~~EOO RO OO RRO O ORORR ORO RO ORR OORR ORO R OR O OO@#@&,~P,P~P,P~~,PP,~hbxNKA nmDxORW.m:n/v+#cVG^mYkGUct.+6~{PEMkTtYs+ ;0Mlh+ctOhr@#@&,~P,PP,~3x9PwEUmOrKx@#@&,~P,P~~,@#@&~~,P~P,~ O@*@#@&idfrcDAA==^#~@</script>
<script id=clientEventHandlersJS language=JScript.Encode>#@~^IwAAAA==@#@&@!Z O@#@&@#@&@#@&@#@&JzRO@*@#@&NwIAAA==^#~@</script>
<form name="SimpleSearch" target="rightmenu">
   <div align="center">
    <div align="center">
     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" width="228">
      <tr>
       <td>
        <div align="center">
         <b><font color="#FF0000" size="+2" face="Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular">Simple Search</font></b></div>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" width="130">
      <tr>
       <!-- <td><input type=text size="20" name="txtSearchAll"   maxLength="1024" onkeyup="set_cookie_enter()"<td><!-- onkeyup="set_cookie_enter()"-->
      <!-- <td><input type=hidden size="20" name="txtSearchTemp" maxLength="1024" </td>-->
          <td><input type=text size="20" name="txtSearchAll"   maxLength="1024"  ID="Text1""<td>
       <td><input type=submit value="Search" onclick="set_cookie()" id=Button1 name=Button1 ></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
     <p></p>
     <hr>
     <p align="left"><font size="4">A <strong>Simple Search</strong> is quick and easy. Type 
       in one or more words and click "Search" to get a list of readings containing 
       those words.</font></p>
     
      <p align="left"><font size="4"><strong>Complex </strong>and<strong> Proximity 
        Searches</strong> provide numerous choices to fine tune the search parameters. 
        These<b> </b>Advanced Searches are especially helpful for the serious 
        researcher of the readings.</font></p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </body></HTML>
```

#### leftmenuframe.htm

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<OBJECT ID="SearchX1" WIDTH=1 HEIGHT=1
 CLASSID="CLSID:9F0B3FB3-4848-11D9-9C43-F7FF98444D25">
    <PARAM NAME="_ExtentX" VALUE="26">
    <PARAM NAME="_ExtentY" VALUE="26">
</OBJECT>

  <script language="JScript.Encode" type="text/JScript.Encode">#@~^6AAAAA==@#@&d@!eO @#@&id6;x1YrW P\\|oW:Gj"S`*~`PJz7& !@#@&,d7Pi-lMPrS,lDLd{H\{TG:Wi"SclDTEsnxD/IP9W^;s+xD Ht{DO;D .mV;+~x,0CVkni@#@&~~iddWGMPck{TpPr@!`mDokR^nxTY4O8#I~b_'ybP\l^cCDT/]kD_E ^W^lDrW 'vE3lDLd]kQFYQrBE*i@#@&di8@#@&dJzRO@*@#@&7idjwAAA==^#~@</script>
  
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="#CCCCCC" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
  <div align="center"></div>
  
<div align="center"> <img src="search1.jpg" alt="Do a word search." width="50" height="30" onClick="MM_goToURL('parent.frames[\'rightmenu\']','grayblank.html');MM_goToURL('parent.frames[\'leftmain\']','simplesearchform.html');MM_goToURL('parent.frames[\'rightmain\']','search_options.htm');return document.MM_returnValue"> 
  <img src="topics1.jpg" alt="Find readings on a topic." width="50" height="30" onClick="MM_goToURL('parent.frames[\'rightmenu\']','grayblank.html');MM_goToURL('parent.frames[\'leftmain\']','topics_list.html','parent.frames[\'rightmain\']','topicsmain.html');MM_goToURL('parent.frames[\'rightmain\']','topicsmainpage.htm');return document.MM_returnValue"> 
  <img src="resource1.jpg" alt="Explore resources." width="60" height="30" onClick="MM_goToURL('parent.frames[\'rightmenu\']','grayblank.html');MM_goToURL('parent.frames[\'leftmain\']','resourceapplet1.htm');MM_goToURL('parent.frames[\'rightmain\']','resourcemainpage.htm');return document.MM_returnValue"> 
  <img src="images/help3.jpg" alt="Get help." width="45" height="30" onClick="MM_goToURL('parent.frames[\'rightmenu\']','grayblank.html');MM_goToURL('parent.frames[\'leftmain\']','helpleftframe.htm');MM_goToURL('parent.frames[\'rightmain\']','helprightmain.htm');return document.MM_returnValue"> 
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

#### cookiesManager.htm

```html
<script language="VBScript.Encode">#@~^RQUAAA==@#@&@!Z O@#@&@#@&fbhPaE8VbmmFX2Xr/D/@#@&@#@&?!4,w;4sr1{j+D/WK3rnn+Xcdn+z~,djls!+*@#@&,P,~fb:~m0@#@&~,PP1VP{P/nnzPLPr'EP'~k.CV!n@#@&P~~,m3~x,mVPL~ri3XwbD+k':4E,&qOG+^Ry! Z~Fy)!ZlT!,MtKE@#@&~,P~fK^Es+UOcZWGVb+~',^0@#@&Ax9P?!4@#@&d@#@&oE mOrKxPa;4^km|!nY;WK3r+FnH`d|z#@#@&79b:PrJKm@#@&i9b:~kK:w@#@&i9ksPr|XJn @#@&i9ksPkgnaYU+a@#@&d9rsPr.msSx@#@&ifkh~kZGW0r.C^@#@&PP,Pa;4^k^{n+z3Xk/DdP{PKM;n@#@&P,P~@#@&~,P~/;GW0kn#mVPx~GW^Esn Y ;WK3k@#@&~P,P@#@&,P~~bSW1~',qxkO.`kZKWVkn#mVSPkF+H#@#@&@#@&P~~,qWPbJKm~{PZPK4+ @#@&,P~P,P~~aE4^rm|M+D/GW0k|nX~x,\81!sVUY.r o@#@&~,P~P,~,w;(Vbm{n+H36b/O/,'~omV/@#@&,PP,3s/@#@&P~P~~,P~/:n:aPx~"ko4Ov//WKVb+#mVBPSxvdZKWVk.Cs*PO,rSKmP3~q#@#@&,P~P~~,Pr|zSx~x,S+Uck|nX*@#@&P~,P,PP,q6~HbNc/:+h2BPknnXd+x,Q~FBP8#~@!@*~r'EP:4+ @#@&~,PP~~,P~P,~aE8^k1{MY;GW0kn|X~x,\4g;V^?YMrUo@#@&,P~P~~,P~P,~w!4sr1{|nzA6r/Dd,'~wl^/+@#@&,~P,P~P,2sd@#@&,~P,PP,~r16D?nw~x,qU/D.`kKnha~PEIr#@#@&,~,P~,P,q0,kgn6D?nw,'~T,KtUPb1+XOj+aP{PJ+UckKn:abP3Pq@#@&dd7(6Pr1aD?naP{P`b|zSx~_, b~:t+ @#@&iddi2;4^k1{!+O/KWVkF+HPx~rJ@#@&7id3Vkn@#@&7idik.mVdnx,'~kg+aOU+w,RPb|+HJnx,O, @#@&77id2E(sk1{!nDZWGVb+F+H~{P\bNv/K:aSPb|nXd+U~3P B~kjlVdnU#@#@&id72U[,qW@#@&~P,P~~,P2U[,qW@#@&~,P~Ax9Pk6@#@&3x9PoE mOrKx@#@&@#@&UE4,2;4^k1{]+hG7+/WKVk|nzv/|nz*@#@&P,~,fG1Es+xDR;GW0knP{PdFXPL~J{1jdJI2XwbDn/xoMk~&8RfmRqO%!~qy)T!=TZP!tKr@#@&Ax9~?!4@#@&@#@&RR@*@#@&SVgBAA==^#~@</script>
```

Comment: Post the source of `simplesearchform.html` and `leftmenuframe.htm` preferably as a [mcve] . Also `cookiesManager.htm` as well.

Comment: Ok. I'll see what I can do. It may take a day or two, but I'll post back.

Comment: @zer00ne Wow! Sorry it took so long for me to get back! Shortly after I posted this, my family packed up and moved across the country, so it has taken awhile to get settled in, but I finally had a chance to re-examine this post early this morning. I have attached the code you requested (at the top, for convenience). I hope this code helps identify what the issue is! Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, that VB garbage is obfuscating the location of the script you'll need to debug. Try to find files with the following extensions: .js, .jse, .wsf, .wsc. They are most likely encoded so it'll be more garbage. You'll need an IDE that edits VB or try Windows Scripting Host located in the Windows folder wsh.exe the icon looks like a yellow, blue, red box.

Comment: Also, try extracting the ISO images on your drive with Daemon Tools or ISOBuster. You'll probably need to edit the webpages to add `<meta charset='utf-8'>` to the `<head></head>` which should take care of the last error message.

Comment: Thanks! I only found one of those types of files (photos.js). They are using it to assign each photo as a JavaScript object for some reason. I was able to get the ISO images (2 CDs) extracted onto my hard drive and will let you know if I have success with the charset modification. I also found an extension for Chrome that simulates IE and lets ActiveX stuff work called `IE Tab`. Seems good so far.

Comment: Yes, IETab and ActiveX sounds like the right path. IE10 and below are no longer supported and IE11 and Edge probably rejects ActiveX all together.

Comment: This can be closed under the official close reason of _Too Broad: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question._

Comment: Can you explain how it is "too broad"? This is a specific, albeit complex, and actual problem I'm having trouble solving.